# Qt qml SwipeView change animation/transition speed

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm using Qt 5.10 and i'm using a SwipeView. I want to change the swipe animation speed, but after reading the docs i could not see how. Is there some workaround to do this?

Comment: That's a good question... I was going to say `Component.onCompleted: contentItem.highlightMoveDuration = 10000` (since it's a `ListView`), but that doesn't work. Neither does messing with the velocity properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason i was trying to do this was because, don't know why, the swipe transition animation was very slow (see below)
this is my code:

```
ColumnLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent

        Item{
            id:modulecontainer

            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            SwipeView{
                id: moduleview
                anchors.fill: parent
                interactive: loggedUser.role==User.AdminRole
                clip: true
                orientation: Qt.Horizontal
                Item {
                    id: firstPage
                    Loader {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        id:moduleLoader


                    }
                }
                Item {
                    id: secondPage
                    Rectangle{
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        color: "red"

                    }
                }
             }
           }
      }
```

[image]

I solved this issue just taking the code of `contentItem` implementation from the source code of SwipeView:

```
  ....  
  SwipeView{
      id: moduleview
      ....
      contentItem: ListView {
                model: moduleview.contentModel
                interactive: moduleview.interactive
                currentIndex: moduleview.currentIndex

                spacing: moduleview.spacing
                orientation: moduleview.orientation
                snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
                boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

                highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
                preferredHighlightBegin: 0
                preferredHighlightEnd: 0
                highlightMoveDuration: 250
                //                    min:10

                maximumFlickVelocity: 4 * (moduleview.orientation === 
                Qt.Horizontal ? width : height)
            }
  }
  ....
```

the result:
[image]

don't know why this solves the problem, but i'm sharing just in case others face the same problem. If more animation speed is wanted just replace the  maximumFlickVelocity factor from 4 to a bigger value